# Plotting 2D array in gnuplot with animation

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, gnuplot

I'm having trouble to plotting 2D array with color mapping. The code below does plot the matrix, but the plot appears after 5s delay. It seams that plot appears in the end of program so animation is imposible. An example in the gnuplot-iostream package with animation works well (a plot is appearing and refreshing before delay, not in the end of program).

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

double matrica[80][120];

void recalculate (int koef)
{
    for (int a=0; a<80; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<120; b++)
        {
            matrica[a][b] = a*b*(sin(koef));
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Gnuplot gp;
    gp << "set xrange [0:110]\nset yrange [0:70]\n";
    gp << "set pm3d\n";
    gp << "set hidden3d\n";
    gp << "set view map\n";
    recalculate(1);
    gp << "splot '-' matrix" <<"\n";
    gp.send1d(matrica);
    gp.flush();
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: What is the `Gnuplot` type ? Are you using some special library ? What header ? Give a link.

Comment: @kebs Yes, he uses [`gnuplot-iostream`](https://gitorious.org/gnuplot-iostream), as mentioned in the question. There is missing a `#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"` and to compile use e.g. `g++ -lutil -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem sendmatrix.cc`. I see also the described behavior.